# Bug in React.js custom fetch hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I have the following custom hook, `useFetch`, in my React (v18.1.0) project to fetch data from a Node.js server.

```
export default function useFetch(url, requestType, headers, body) {
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  console.log('Inside useFetch hook');
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Inside useEffect in the useFetch hook');
    const controller = new AbortController();
    async function retrieveData(reqUrl) {
      try {
        console.log('Inside the useFetch try block');
        const res = await fetchData(
          reqUrl,
          requestType,
          headers,
          body,
          controller.signal
        );
        console.log('Done with fetch; this is the server response ', res);
        setData(res);
        setLoading(false);
        console.log('Done with useFetch try block.');
      } catch (err) {
        if (err.name === 'AbortError') {
          console.log('Fetch aborted');
        } else {
          setError(true);
          setData(err);
          setLoading(false);
        }
      }
    }
    retrieveData(url);
    return () => {
      controller.abort();
    };
  }, []);
  return { loading, error, data };
}
```

My useFetch hook uses a function called `fetchData` to send a fetch request to the server.

```
async function fetchData(url, requestType, headers, payload, abortSignal) {
  console.log('Inside the fetch function');
  let res = await fetch(url, {
    method: requestType,
    headers: headers,
    body: payload,
    signal: abortSignal ? abortSignal : null,
  });
  if (res.ok) {
    const resJson = await res.json();
    console.log('Returning value from fetch function');
    return { status: res.status, response: resJson };
  } else {
    await fetchErrorHandler(res);
  }
}
```

The `useFetch` hook is invoked once in my `VideoPlayer` component.

```
function VideoPlayer() {
  const { videoId } = useParams();
  const url = `http://localhost:5000/videos/${videoId}`;
  const { loading, error, data } = useFetch(url, 'GET', {}, null);

  return (
    <div>
      {loading && <div />}
      {!loading && error && <h2>{data.message}</h2>}
      {!loading && !error && (
        <video width={600} height={450} controls src={data.response.videoUrl}>
          Cannot display video player.
        </video>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that when the `VideoPlayer` component is mounted to the DOM and `useFetch` is called, the execution flow looks like this:
[Execution flow of `useFetch` hook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY8PM.png). As is seen in the image, everything seems fine until the line `Inside the fetch function` is printed in the console. After this, the `useEffect` hook within the `useFetch` is called again, for reasons I'm unable to understand (my dependency array is empty and, moreover, there's no state change at this point). Then, it tries to execute the `fetch` another time, aborts it, and then eventually returns a response, presumably to the original `fetch` request. At the end of this process, `useFetch` is called yet again. If anyone can help me shed some light on why the hook is behaving this way, instead of simply executing the `fetch` request once and returning the response, I will greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you use React in [StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) - this is the default for apps created with create-react-app.

In strict mode, [effects can fire twice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j8s01ThR7bQ) while in development mode. You can verify that this causes your problem by running a production build. If the problem goes away, it is likely caused by StrictMode.

My suggestion is to not change anything - actually, your code seems to work fine: the first effect execution triggers a fetch, then the second effect execution aborts the initial fetch and fetches for a second time. This is exactly, what the code is expected to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **axios** to deal with API

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).